# for loop seems to ignore list values

Tags: python, pandas

The second for loop in the following code appears to ignore the values in the root list for the "TEST TWO" results. I can't figure out why - any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['id', 'issye_type']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

# print(df)

root = ['issue A',
        'issue B'
        ]

print('\nTEST ONE')
for root in root:
    b = df.issye_type.str.startswith(root, na=False).sum()
    print('# of', root, "issues: ", b)

print('\nTEST TWO')
for root in root:
    c = df.issye_type.str.startswith(root, na=False).sum()
    print('# of', root, "issues: ", c)
```

Result:

```
TEST ONE
# of issue A issues:  0
# of issue B issues:  0

TEST TWO
# of i issues:  0
# of s issues:  0
# of s issues:  0
# of u issues:  0
# of e issues:  0
# of   issues:  0
# of B issues:  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same variable to hold the list and the iteration variable:

```
for root in root:
```

So when the first loop is done, `root` now contains the last string in the list, not the list. Therefore, the second loop iterates over the characters in that string.

Use a different variable:

```
print('\nTEST ONE')
for r in root:
    b = df.issye_type.str.startswith(r, na=False).sum()
    print('# of', r, "issues: ", b)

print('\nTEST TWO')
for r in root:
    c = df.issye_type.str.startswith(r, na=False).sum()
    print('# of', r, "issues: ", c)
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was user error! Thank you so much - it was driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

I see your bug use `for root in roots:` is better in the two loops.

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['id', 'issye_type']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

# print(df)

roots = ['issue A',
        'issue B'
        ]

print('\nTEST ONE')
for root in roots:
    b = df.issye_type.str.startswith(root, na=False).sum()
    print('# of', root, "issues: ", b)

print('\nTEST TWO')
for root in roots:
    c = df.issye_type.str.startswith(root, na=False).sum()
    print('# of', root, "issues: ", c)
```

Else in the second loop global `root` variable is erased by the `root` variable browsering in first loop.